# issue with Wifi

Tags: 16.04, wireless, hp

2)Unable to see many wifi networks while on my windows os there are many wifi networks available.Also on my friends ubuntu 16.04 all the other networks are shown.

1)The speed which i'm getting is pretty bad, wifi is running much faster on my phone, even a google search isn't working.
(I am typing these answers on window)

On typing

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2 on terminal

The output was:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This is what it shows

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
edited

Comment: Please see the duplicate. Some cases require `ant_sel=1` and some require `ant_sel=2` Try =1 first and if there is no improvement, try again with =2.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Worked liked a charm 

This community is amazing !!

Comment: Glad it's working. Have fun!